# How to create AWS IAM role with ServiceAccount and attach to Kubernetes DaemonSet

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam

I found [that documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-service-account-iam-policy-and-role.html) that we can add AWS IAM role to kubernetes serviceaccount and attach to Pods. And what I'm supposed to do is I want to attach that service account to DaemonSet instead of Pods level permission. But I configured same as that documentation and attached to DaemonSet but I've encountered following error message after that:

`Aws::STS::Errors::AccessDenied error="Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`

Is that meant those type of serviceaccount with IAM role cannot be attached to DaemonSet?

Comment: Could you please add your DaemonSet yaml? I checked [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/) and there is an example with service account in a deployment so there shouldn't be any issues. Additionally take a look [here](https://medium.com/@dinuka.roshan/so-we-started-using-iam-roles-for-service-accounts-in-our-kubernetes-cluster-c02851f948b) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/specify-service-account-role.html).

Comment: No, it means the IAM Role for the _caller_ is missing `{"Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity", "Effect": "Allow", ...}` as shown in [this relevant GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/23#issuecomment-534693929)

Comment: @Jakub my bad, I forgot to add `openid_url`. Can you post your comment as answer? I'll mark as correct answer.

Comment: @mdaniel my bad, I forgot to add openid_url. Can you post your comment as answer? I'll upvote it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that meant those type of serviceaccount with IAM role cannot be attached to DaemonSet?

No,there shouldn't be any issues with that. I checked [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/) and there is an example with service account in a deployment.

---

As @PPShein mentioned in comments the issue occurs because he forgot to add the `openid_url`.

Please refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-service-account-iam-policy-and-role.html) and [this](https://marcincuber.medium.com/amazon-eks-with-oidc-provider-iam-roles-for-kubernetes-services-accounts-59015d15cb0c) documentation.